# Отрицание при сослагательном наклонении

Tags: семантика, сослагательное-наклонение

> Так в  Ростове-на-Дону в ботаническом саду Южного федерального университета все елки были обвиты... колючей проволокой! Да-да, вы все правильно прочитали, но следует сразу же признать - *это сделано, дабы деревья не украли (срубили), либо же повредили.*

(Из новостной ленты, курсив мой - b-s)

Собственно, вопрос такой. Верна ли выделенная конструкция грамматически, и если нет, то как её исправить с минимальными затратами?

Ну и при желании хорошо бы, конечно, разобрать причину возникновения подобного недоразумения.

Comment: Я весьма признателен за конструктивную правку моего текста. но расставлять знаки в цитате не надо.

Comment: Простите, виноват! Я просто не понял, что к чему, всё выделенное цитата или нет. Но это совсем не оправдание, я был не прав.

Answer (score 2):

Сослагательное наклонение тут ни при чём.

Выделенная конструкция грамматически не верна.

Нужен повтор отрицания при втором глаголе и не нужна запятая при одиночном союзе "либо":

***...это сделано, дабы деревья не украли (срубили) либо же не повредили.***

Comment: *это сделано, дабы деревья не украли (срубили) либо же не повредили.* - а почему "либо"? И почему ни при чем? Вот люблю я таких самонадеянных отвечальщиков))). Лишь бы прокукарекать.

Comment: @behemothus - ты не прав, Уася

Comment: Как-нибудь разберусь без вас.